# vue3 and typescript reactive function change the type of inner object

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, types

I am using vue3 and typescript, this is my code:

```
   const data = reactive({
      bytes : new Uint8Array(),
    })
```

my confusion is that
when mouse hover on `data`, its type is:

```
const data: {
    bytes: {
        [x: number]: number;
        readonly BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: number;
        readonly buffer: {
            readonly byteLength: number;
            slice: (begin: number, end?: number | undefined) => ArrayBuffer;
            readonly [Symbol.toStringTag]: string;
        } | {
            ...;
        };
        ... 30 more ...;
        readonly [Symbol.toStringTag]: "Uint8Array";
    };
}
```

but when mouse hover on `bytes`, its type is:

```
(property) bytes: Uint8Array
```

is that the `reactive` function change the type of the `bytes`? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Why do you need to fix it? This is what it is, a reactive copy of original object.

Comment: when I use `data.bytes` as a parameter in some functions, the typescript compiler throws error like this:
`Argument of type '{ [x: number]: number; readonly BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: number; readonly buffer: { readonly byteLength: number; slice: (begin: number, end?: number | undefined) => ArrayBuffer; } | { readonly byteLength: number; slice: (begin: number, end?: number | undefined) => SharedArrayBuffer; }; ... 28 more ...; includes: (searchEl...' is not assignable to 
parameter of type 'Uint8Array'.`